# Trying to save csv file with PHP takes too long

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I am trying to save some data to csv file with PHP.
So far I tried a few examples I found online, some of those work but it took 10+ mins to create the file.

Below is the code that works and takes too long:

```
$list = array(
['Name', 'Age', 'Gender'],
['Bob', 20, 'Male'],
['John', 25, 'Male'],
['Baba', 30, 'Female']);

// Open a file in write mode ('w')

$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

// Loop through file pointer and a line

foreach ($list as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Can anyone help with resolving this issue, I am not sure if this happens due to server configuration or if this is normal behaviour?

[EDIT]
I am trying to save the csv file from Wordpress functions.php when a post is added or updated.
I tried creating a html file and running the script from custom php file and it worked normally so it seems that the problem is related the WP.

Thanks!

Comment: it seems your code is right, there might be problems with your server

Comment: What server are you using? Does saving other files via PHP take that long too?

Comment: We are using Cloud SSD VPS with PHP 7.3. Saving json files works normally

Comment: Have you looked at your server error logs?

Comment: Yes, there is no error log when I run the script. I just edited my question because it seems that running the function from WP functions.php is causing the problem. I did not think this was relevant so I didn't mention it earlier

Comment: Are you using session anywhere before this script get called ?

Comment: No, there is no session in the script. The weirdest part is that json file gets saved immediately but csv takes that long

Comment: For debugging: Does it also take that long if you replace  `fputcsv($fp, $fields);` with `fwrite($fp, join($fields,',')."\n");` ?